# Validate IP and Network address from read-host input

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script where a user would input both Network address and an IP address for the purpose of creating static route `CLI` templates.

1. For the IP address, I can't seem to get the `[ipaddress]` option to work, and that seems to be the best one. For the network address, How can i make this work?  I've read through another post with the using the read-host option but I'm not sure how to tie that into this.
2. For the Network address, is my only option a regex because those options that I've seen seem flawed.

   ```
   $fwA = read-host "Enter hostA"

   $fwB= read-Host "Enter hostB"
   ```

I want to validate this is either an IP address (/32 not needed) or a valid network address.

```
$Net1 = read-host "Enter Network x.x.x.x/x"
```

I want to validate this is an IP address

```
$GW1= read-host "Enter Next Hop x.x.x.x"
$route1 += @("$fwA","$fwB","$Net1","$GW1")
write-host ""
Write-Host "Route 1 : "$route1[0] "/" $route1[1] "=" $route1[2] $route1[3]
Write-Host "set static route" $route1[2] $route1[3] "on" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: Without trying to be rude - did you try to search for it? Something like this has been asked several times even here in SO: [POWERSHELL validate IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BPOWERSHELL%5D+validate+IP+address). Some of the answers might guide you to the right direction.

Comment: Apologies, I did, and the validation examples I found seemed to have some weaknesses but I was able to get the [IPaddress] working today.  I was not applying it correctly.

Comment: Great. You might share your solution here for others searching for the  same or a similar problem.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the IP Address, I use a completely different approach:

By passing the Workstation/Server name as a parameter to the input type System.Net.DNS cast

For example, if the FQDN name of the host is ABCTest-DEV, then the following script will reveal the IP address of ABCTest-Dev provided, the host has a DNS record already available in the domain.

```bsh
$ipaddr = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('ABCTest-Dev')|Where AddressFamily -EQ 'InterNetwork'
Write-Host 'This IPV4 Address of the Host is: '$ipaddr
```